# Validate Chilean RUT using Target.Value on 2 columns

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to validate Chilean RUT (12345678-9) using the [math algorithm](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rol_%C3%9Anico_Tributario) which works perfectly but the procedure is applied only when the RUT it's stored in one cell.
So when the user inputs a RUT it will display a `MsgBox` letting the user know the result.

```
RUT
----------
01234567-8 ' MSGBOX "THIS IS CORRECT/INCORRECT."
```

Now, our database stores RUT in two parts, the RUT itself `01234567` and the check digit -the number after the score symbol- `8`.
I was thinking of a way to store and validate the RUT when the check digit column is changed but I can't figure how to store both values at the same time using `Target.Value`.
Our excel "template" for the DB

```
RUT          DV
----------------
01234567     8  ' DISPLAY ALERT AS SOON AS DV IS ADDED?
```

My code validating one cell:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Columns("C")) Is Nothing Then
    On Error Resume Next
    
    rute = Target.Value
    arut = UCase(Target.Value)

    Rut = Replace("0000" & Rut, ".", "", 1)
    If InStr(1, Rut, "-") > 0 Then Rut = Left(rute, InStr(1, rute, "-") - 1)
    Rut = Right(rute, 8)
    suma = 0
    For i = 1 To 8
    suma = suma + Val(Mid(rute, i, 1)) * Val(Mid("32765432", i, 1))
    Next i
    dv = 11 - (suma Mod 11)
    If dv = 10 Then dv = "K"
    If dv = 11 Then dv = 0

    'If Right(arut, 1) = CStr(dv) Then MsgBox ("Rut " & rute & " Correcto")
    If Right(arut, 1) <> CStr(dv) Then MsgBox ("Rut: " & rute & " Incorrecto.")
    If rute = "" Then MsgBox ("Campo(s) modificado(s).")
End If
End Sub
```

Any hints on what should I do or other approach it's appreciated.

NOTE: In cell formula isn't possible due to requirements.

Comment: You don't need to use only `Target.Value`  - you can access both parts of the RUT using (eg) `Target.EntireRow.Cells(1).Value` and `Target.EntireRow.Cells(2).Value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example (omitting your checking code)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range, rute, chk, c As Range

    Set rng = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("C:D"))

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        For Each c in rng.cells

            rute = c.entirerow.cells(3).value
            chk = c.entirerow.cells(4).value

            'validate rute and chk here and
            '  show msgbox if needed


        Next c   
    End If

End Sub
```